# Are bi-infinite sequences amenable to generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Is there a way to make sense of a bi-infinite generating function?  For example, consider the series
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty t^k,
$$
corresponding to the sequence $\dots,1,1,1,\dots$.

Is there a way to formally associate this series with a function of $t$ so that the usual generatingfunctionology applies?

I apologize if this sounds vague.

Comment: $\sum_{k\geq 0}t^k$ converges if $|t|<1$, $\sum_{k\geq 1}t^{-k}$ converges if $|t|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the situation in [Fourier analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis).  In the simplest case you can think of this as the study of sums
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k z^k$$
where $z$ is restricted to the unit circle $(z=\exp 2\pi i \theta)$. You still have to worry about convergence issues; in particular the example you give $(c_k=1)$ doesn't converge.